# Relational Algebra query into mySQL

Tags: mysql, join, cartesian-product

https://gyazo.com/a3309126ae04983c8d38d82677e4480c Given this general query

L is a list of attributes Where R_1, ... , R_n is relations. C is a condition.

How would I express this in SQL?

It basically does cartesian product from R1 to Rn, then uses a selection operator for the condition, then selects the attributes it needs. I'm confused on how to do the cartesian product from R1 to Rn in SQL.

MY ATTEMPT

```
SELECT L FROM (R1, R2, ..., RN) WHERE C
```

Wouldn't this be right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comma-based syntax for joins is considered obsolete. Here's the equivalent for cartesian products:

```
SELECT L
FROM R1
CROSS JOIN R2
CROSS JOIN R3
...
CROSS JOIN RN
WHERE C;
```

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html for more information.